# What are the differences among these notions in probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a Borel probability measure on $[a,b]$. Here are several notions:

(1)A probability measure whose support is $[a,b]$

(2)A continuous random variable

(3)A random variable with a probability density function (according to wiki, this is called the absolutely continuous random variable)

(4)A probability distribution without mass points

(I want (2),(3),(4) to distribute on the whole interval [I don't know how to describe this precisely])

What are the differences among them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concepts 1.-4. are sometimes described in terms of random variables, and sometimes in terms of probability measures. These are different things, but you can map between them; any random variable describes a probability measure, and vice versa.

In the below, I'm going to ignore the difference between random variables and probability measures, and just focus on what the concepts 1.-4. say about the distributions. As requested, I'll also assume that all four concepts describe distributions with support $[a, b]$.

Saying 2., that $X$ is a "continuous random variable", doesn't really have a standard definition:

- It could mean $X$ is supported on an uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$, in which case you get 1.
- It could mean $X$ has a continuous distribution function, in which case you get 4.
- It could mean $X$ has a density $p$, in which case you get 3.

Each of these assumptions is stronger than the last: 3. $\implies$ 4. $\implies$ 1., and the implications are strict. Most of these are fairly straightforward to show; for an example of a random variable $X$, supported on $[0,1]$, satisfying 4. but not 3., let $X$ be a mixture of the uniform distribution and the Cantor distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized that maybe I could drop "the support is [a,b]" for 3 and 4, and instead change 3 to the probability density function being positive on [a,b], and 4 to the cumulative distribution function being strictly increasing. Then we can directly say 3=>4=>1, right?

Comment: By "support", which definition are you referring to in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#In_probability_and_measure_theory

Comment: And could you please propose an example where 1 is true but 4 is false?

Comment: @Ypbor I'm using the [measure-theoretic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)). Yes, with those additions, 3 => 4 => 1. If X is a mixture of a uniform distribution and a mass point, then it satisfies 1 but not 4.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#In_probability_and_measure_theory This part contains two definitions of support, one starts with "more formally", the other starts with "the support of a continuous random variable". I guess you are referring to the former? (BTW, are they equivalent?)

Comment: And is "no mass point" defined as for all $x \in [a,b]$, the probability measure of $\left\{x\right\}$ is zero?

Comment: @Ypbor Yes, the "more formally" one. And yes, "no mass point" means $\mathbb P(X = x) = 0$ for all $x$.